# Paste single strings with an array in Bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash

What would be a bash equivalent of the following R function?

```
vec=4:9
out=paste0("foo_",vec,"_bar")
out

"foo_4_bar" "foo_5_bar" "foo_6_bar" "foo_7_bar" "foo_8_bar" "foo_9_bar"
```

Comment: Is `vec=4:9` just an example (where the input could really be any array), or is it genuinely the case that it'll always be generated as a range between two constants?

Comment: `echo foo_{4..9}_bar`?

Comment: @twalberg, you'd want to end the quotes before and after the brace expansion. And that conflicts with the "just an example" specified by the OP above, to the effect that they actually want to be able to add prefix and suffix to *any* array, not only one with a numeric range bounded by constants.

Comment: (`{$start..$end}` doesn't work due to brace expansion happening before parameter expansion, hence the "bounded by constants").

Comment: @Remi.b, ...perhaps using a function definition that was as generic as you wanted your resulting shell function to be might have been an approach that would cause less confusion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Correct on the quotes... Fixed that. However, I'm not seeing the other stipulations anywhere in the question... Aside from having the output quoted as shown, the above `echo` is literally "a bash equivalent of the following R function"...

Comment: @twalberg, see the title -- it's "with an array", not "with a numeric range". That they chose to use a numeric range as a very terse way to generate a sample array seems to have been rather misleading.

Comment: @Remi.b, did I misunderstand the question? The accepted answer only works with a very small subset of possible arrays (actually, it works with numeric ranges, not arrays at all); I took your first comment on the question to mean that you were looking for a more general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use declare an array with suffix and prefix and then use brace expansion to populate incrementing numbers:

```
arr=("foo_" "_bar") # array with suffix and prefix
echo "${arr[0]}"{4..9}"${arr[1]}" # brace expansion

foo_4_bar foo_5_bar foo_6_bar foo_7_bar foo_8_bar foo_9_bar
```

Comment: Hmm. I mean, this works, but it only works in a pretty specific scenario (where the array is generated via a brace expansion), not with any arbitrary array.

Comment: @sjsam, ...when the array to the elements of which a prefix and suffix are joined (the `4:9`, in R terms) is something other than a numeric range anchored by constants. See the discussion with the OP in comments on the question, that restricting the problem domain in that way was not their intent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use brace expansion:

```
$ echo foo_{4..9}_bar
foo_4_bar foo_5_bar foo_6_bar foo_7_bar foo_8_bar foo_9_bar
$ out=( foo_{4..9}_bar )
$ echo "${out[1]}"
foo_5_bar
```

Answer (score 2):

This works even if your `vec` is not generated via a brace expansion:

```
vec=( {4..9} ) # would work even with vec=( *.txt ) or readarray -t vec <file, etc.
out=( "${vec[@]/#/foo_}" ) # add foo_ prefix
out=( "${out[@]/%/_bar}" ) # add _bar suffix
declare -p out # print resulting array definition
```

See [the Parameter Expansion page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) on the bash-hackers wiki, particularly the "Anchoring" section under "Search and Replace".